# Does Netsh.exe command overwrite existing firewall rules?

Tags: windows-firewall, netsh

I'm using a netsh command that add a firewall rule on windows 2012 r2 server.

My command is like this:

```
Netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="name" protocol="TCP" localport=1234 dir=in enable=yes action=allow
```

What happen if i already have a rule with another name and same localport and protocol?

My command will overwrite that rule or it will create another one on same port?

I've tried to find any documentation, but i've found nothing about that.

Comment: Although I don't know the answer to your question, I'll point out that Netsh isn't a PowerShell command.  It is always preferable to use native PowerShell commands if available.  In this case, you should take a look at the [NetSecurity module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/?view=win10-ps).

Comment: i'm sorry, i mean that i use netsh into a powershell script. i modify my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PowerShell module called NetSecurity.
You can make a statement in powershell which can tell if the rule already exist or not.

`Get-NetFirewallRule` you can use this command to discover which firewall rules are already defined.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/?view=win10-ps

Comment: i'm using older version of powershell and Get-NetFirewallRule cmdlet is not available!

Comment: If you don't get an answer until later today. I will try it and report back to you